# when i used to diffrent @keyframes only the first on is working while the other one isn't

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

when i used to diffrent @keyframes only the first on is working while the other one isn't
when i put the   @keyframes moving-from-left-to-right first and use it with .text it worked because it is the first one but the second  @keyframes  right-to-left  that i used with the .img class is not workig and it isn't have the same coloring code as the first one

```
 .img2 {
        float: right;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
        margin: 20px;
        animation-name: right-to-left;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease;
    }
    
    

.text {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: large;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    animation-name: moving-from-left-to-right;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes moving-from-left-to-right {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-500px);
        s
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(-400
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-200px
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-100px
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px
    }
}

@keyframes right-to-left {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(100
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(50px
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px
    }
}
```

Comment: your css code seems broken. 0% { transform: translateX(-500px);
        s <<< here?
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(-400 <<< here?
    }

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why it doesn't work as expected:

1. You are not closing your brackets

   `transform: translateX(100`  should be `transform: translateX(100)`
2. You have some values in px and some without px.

   `transform: translateX(200px);` is good,
   `transform: translateX(100` is bad (no closed bracket, no px)
3. In the part of code

   ```
   @keyframes moving-from-left-to-right {
   0% {
       transform: translateX(-500px);
       s
   }
   ```

what is this `s` doing there?